# Rounded button - how to strech text inside it to full width

Tags: html, css, styles

I have created an image to illustrate my problem:

[image]

As you can see. I have a large rounded button. it consists of 3 images. One image is on the right side, another on the left size and another one in the middle.

The left and right images are quite wide because there is a gradient going on in the button so I cannot make them just 5px wide. The problem now is, that the text inside is limited to the middle area. I would like it to stretch across the entire button.

Here are my styles:

```
#index-navigation ul li a {
    height: 96px;
    line-height: 96px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #333;
    background: url('/images/btn_grey@2x-right.png') right center no-repeat;
    padding-right: 100px;
}
#index-navigation ul li a span.left {
    background: url('/images/btn_grey@2x-left.png') left center no-repeat;
    padding-left: 100px;
}
#index-navigation ul li a span.middle {
    background: url('/images/btn_grey@2x-middle.png') left center repeat-x;
}
```

How to edit the style to be able to have the anchor take the entire width of the button? Like this:

[image]

Comment: why not doing it like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Qc9cU/2/

Comment: @EricFortis, probably because the images are not just a rounded border?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to move your text to a separate `span` to be able to stretch it across the whole `a`. Just give your `.left` and `.right` the appropriate backgrounds, let the `a` hold the main bg - http://jsfiddle.net/JutRB/3/

```
a {
    height: 96px;
    width: 350px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #333;
    background: beige;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

a span.left, a span.right {
    float: left;
    background: yellow;
    height: 96px;
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
}

a span.right {
    float: right;
    background: pink;
}

a span.text {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    top: 30px;
    width: 100%;
}
​
```

**UPDATE**

Or if you want a CSS3 solution and don't care about the older IE-s then you can use the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements with much cleaner markup - http://jsfiddle.net/JutRB/4/

Comment: Updated to have a cleaner HTML (however won't work in older IE-s)

Comment: Hi Zoltan. It works expect my background images are transparent. So the left and right images are not very nice. You can see the middle image in the background.

Comment: give your `a:before` and `a:after` `the border-radius` too - http://jsfiddle.net/JutRB/5/

Answer (score 0):

It's the sliding doors technique, falling out of favour nowadays with border-radius and graceful degradation to the old browsers getting traction in the marketplace.

The a tag in your demo does take the whole area as it wraps the inner 2 spans, you want to make sure you remove the width declaration though so it extends with the text.

If you've got a demo we could debug it a bit more specifically for you.